# change a view programmatically with swift-slide-menu

Tags: ios, swift

I am using this library: [swift-slide-menu](https://github.com/PhilippeBoisney/Swift-Slide-Menu)

Is there any way to change a view programmatically? I am using the same viewcontroller to show two different datasets in a tableview. I have two buttons in the menu, one for each dataset. When clicking on button1 I go to the ListVC and everything works fine. When clicking on button2 I go to an empty ViewController that sets the url for the dataset and segues right away to ListVC.

When I do the segue, the menu button is not shown in ListVC. This is probably because I am not adding a childView to the BaseViewController when I segue. But is there any way to add a code inside my empty ViewController that adds ListVC as a childView, instead of doing a normal segue?

PS.
I am trying to prevent having the same code inside two different viewcontrollers and having 2 copies of the same vc in storyboard.

```
class ViewController: BaseViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addChildView("AllDatasetID", titleOfChildren: "All data", iconName: "icon1") //ListVC
        addChildView("FilteredDatasetID", titleOfChildren: "My data", iconName: "icon2") //EmptyVC that segues to ListVC

    }
}



class EmptyVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toListVC", sender: self)

    }


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "toListVC" {

            if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? ListVC {
                destinationVC.theUrl = Settings.myFilterUrl
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not about to learn an old sdk like that, but I would guess considering it hasn't been updated in two years, that it is just broken. I would reccomend some https://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift

Comment: It is not broken, just trying to get this functionality to work I explained in the question.

Comment: You won't find anyone that answers this. The SDK in out of date and only a handful of people ever used it in the first place. Sorry... The SDK looks too old style Android anyhow. I would trash is for that reason alone.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your personal opinion.

Comment: The problem I am trying to solve has little to do with the library I am using. It has much more to do with best practices using swift. In the comment here above, there is a link to a raywenderlich tutorial, that tutorial uses the same way to add childrenViews to a view controller as the library I am using. The question is, how to programmatically call a change when using childrenViews.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to access inside the ListVC a variable from the menu that stored the title for the current view. The menu subclasses BaseViewController and several variables are accessable from the BaseViewController through the navigationController.

```
class ViewController: BaseViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        addChildView("ListVCScreenID", titleOfChildren: "My datapoints", iconName: "icon1")
        addChildView("ListVCScreenID", titleOfChildren: "All datapoints", iconName: "icon2")
    }
}

class ListVC: UIViewController {
    var theUrl: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

        let vc = self.navigationController?.viewControllers
            var counter = 0
            for v in vc! {
                if v as? ViewController != nil {
                    print("title is: \(v.title)")
                    if(v.title == "My datapoints") {
                        theUrl = "getMyData"
                    }
                    else {
                        theUrl = "getAllData"
                    }

            }
       }
    }
}
```